# Change Hive configuration properties for HDInsight Cluster

Tags: powershell, azure, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I know, that when we submit a Map-Reduce or Hive Job using Azure PowerShell, we can pass job configuration. But is there a way to remote desktop or through PowerShell change HDInsight cluster properties forever. As there are some config changes I need to make which will be applicable to all jobs.

Answer (score 2):

You can recreate the cluster and specify those properties at cluster create time. Please see the sample section in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn593759.aspx

Comment: I know this feature, but for example if I need tez as my hive execution engine. Can I set those configurations too using PowerShell script?

Comment: You should be able to set Tez as execution engine as part of Hive script itself.